# Unicode-math: Use several calligraphic fonts in parallel

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I would like to use e.g. the calligraphic font from two different fonts conveniently in the same document.

For example in the snippet below, how can I load in parallel e.g. the calligraphic fonts from LatinModern and use it via a command like `\symcallatin{ABC}`?

I have already found some solutions that rely on switching the whole font e.g. using `mathversion`. But I would like to avoid this and instead have a dedicated command that allows to write certain symbols in a predefined font.
How can this be achieved?

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal},StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
    $\symcal{ABC}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you do `\symscr` you get the glyphs from Pagella Math.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your reply. But isn't that (in general) a different font than the calligraphics from Pagella math?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining different fonts in Math mode was traditionally implemented with the `\fam` primitive.
`unicode-math` does not use `\fam` by default for OTF fonts, but you can change that by manually loading the fonts into mathgroups.
The additional fonts are not loaded by the `unicode-math` machinery, so `range` etc. is not available:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn\definemathgroup#1#2#3#4{
  \fontspec_set_family:Nnn\l_my_math_font_family{SmallCapsFont={},ItalicFont={},BoldFont={},Script=Math,#3}{#4}
  \exp_args:Nc\new@mathgroup{\string#1}
  \::c\::n\::f\:::\new@symbolfont{\string#1}{TU}{\l_my_math_font_family}{\seriesdefault}{\shapedefault}
  \cs_new:Npn#1##1{#2{\fam\use:c{\string#1}##1}}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\definemathgroup\mathmyothercal\symcal{}{Latin Modern Math}
\definemathgroup\mathtgcal\symcal{}{Tex Gyre DejaVu Math}
\begin{document}
\[ABC=\symcal{ABC}=\mathtgcal{ABC}=\mathmyothercal{ABC}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the command `\definemathgroup` the second parameter(always `\symcal` in the examples above) select the math alphabet. This can be replaced by the other `\sym...` commands from `unicode-math` to load other math alphabets, e.g. `\smybb` for blackbord bold, `\symfrak`, `\symit`, `\symnormal`, ...

Comment: Thanks, that looks really great! Could you add what needs to be changed in the case other than calligraphic fonts are desired (e.g. `fraktur`, `blackboard`, `typewriter`, `upright`, `italic` etc. )?

Comment: @bonanza Just replace `\symcal` with the corresponding `\sym...`. A full list is to be found in the `unicode-math` documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I thought its more complicated as I believed that the `\fontspec_set_family: ....` line only loads the `script` glyphs.

Comment: @bonanza Probably because of `Script=Math`, but that does not mean to only load script glyphs, it indicates that the font is used for mathematical writing instead of text in latin script, arabic script, etc.

Comment: I added a issue to unicode-math for this https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/481