# How to use both Computer Modern and Latin Modern's Calligraphic \mathcal at the same time in LuaTeX with unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode-math, computer-modern, mathcal

Here's my MWE:

[image: Computer Modern vs. Latin Modern's mathbb and mathcal]

```
% !TEX program = lualatex

% DOCUMENT CLASS
\documentclass[11pt,preview,varwidth,%
border={5pt 5pt 5pt 5pt}% left bottom right top
]{standalone}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb} % Math packages

\let\oldmathbb\mathbb % Computer Modern blackboard bold
\let\oldmathcal\mathcal % Computer Modern calligraphic
\AtBeginDocument{\def\mathbb{\oldmathbb}} % Redefine \mathbb to use Computer Modern
\AtBeginDocument{\def\mathcal{\oldmathcal}} % Redefine \mathcal to use Computer Modern

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\let\newmathbb\mathbb % Latin Modern blackboard bold
\let\newmathcal\mathcal % Latin Modern calligraphic

\newcommand{\AtoZ}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

% START OF DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathbb|: \(\mathbb{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Latin Modern's \verb|\mathbb|: \(\newmathbb{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathcal|: \(\mathcal{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Latin  Modern's \verb|\mathcal|: \(\newmathcal{\AtoZ}\)
\end{document}
% END OF DOCUMENT
```

I am trying to mainly use Computer Modern's blackboard bold (`\mathbb`) and calligraphic (`\mathcal`) fonts in `LuaTeX` with the `unicode-math` package simply because I prefer them over Latin Modern's (in those particular cases) but I would still want to be able to access Latin Modern's blackboard bold and calligraphic fonts, hence the `\newmathbb` and `\newmathcal` macros.

#### As seen from my MWE, I seem to have a problem accessing Computer Modern's calligraphic font for some reason.

I've read [this TeX.SX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637781/) but when I used `\setmathfont[range={cal}]{cmsy10}`, I ended up not being able to access Latin Modern's calligraphic font instead as it seems to globally change every calligraphic font to `cmsy10`:

[image: Attempted Solution #1]

```
% !TEX program = lualatex

% DOCUMENT CLASS
\documentclass[11pt,preview,varwidth,%
border={5pt 5pt 20pt 5pt}% left bottom right top
]{standalone}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb} % Math packages

\let\oldmathbb\mathbb % Computer Modern blackboard bold
\AtBeginDocument{\def\mathbb{\oldmathbb}} % Redefine \mathbb to use Computer Modern

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\let\newmathbb\mathbb % Latin Modern blackboard bold
\let\newmathcal\mathcal % Latin Modern calligraphic
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{cmsy10} % Computer Modern calligraphic

\newcommand{\AtoZ}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

% START OF DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathbb|: \(\mathbb{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Latin Modern's \verb|\mathbb|: \(\newmathbb{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathcal|: \(\mathcal{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Latin  Modern's \verb|\mathcal|: \(\newmathcal{\AtoZ}\)
\end{document}
% END OF DOCUMENT
```

(I received the warnings `Package fontspec Warning: Font "cmsy10" does not contain requested Script "Math".`, `Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (ssty) not available for font 'cmsy10' with script '' and language 'Default'.`, and `Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (ssty) not available for font 'cmsy10' with script '' and language 'Default'.`)

I've also read [another TeX.SX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439482/) but when I tried its approach I still couldn't use both Computer Modern and Latin Modern's calligraphic fonts at the same time:

[image: Attempted Solution #2]

```
% !TEX program = lualatex

% DOCUMENT CLASS
\documentclass[11pt,preview,varwidth,%
border={5pt 5pt 20pt 5pt}% left bottom right top
]{standalone}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb} % Math packages

\let\oldmathbb\mathbb % Computer Modern blackboard bold
\AtBeginDocument{\def\mathbb{\oldmathbb}} % Redefine \mathcal to use Computer Modern

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\let\newmathbb\mathbb % Latin Modern blackboard bold

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn\definemathgroup#1#2#3#4{
  \fontspec_set_family:Nnn\l_my_math_font_family{SmallCapsFont={},ItalicFont={},BoldFont={},Script=Math,#3}{#4}
  \exp_args:Nc\new@mathgroup{\string#1}
  \::c\::n\::f\:::\new@symbolfont{\string#1}{TU}{\l_my_math_font_family}{\seriesdefault}{\shapedefault}
  \cs_new:Npn#1##1{#2{\fam\use:c{\string#1}##1}}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definemathgroup{\oldmathcal}{\symcal}{}{cmsy10} % Computer Modern calligraphic
\AtBeginDocument{\def\mathcal{\oldmathcal}} % Redefine \mathcal to use Computer Modern

\definemathgroup{\newmathcal}{\symcal}{}{Latin Modern Math} % Latin Modern calligraphic

\newcommand{\AtoZ}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

% START OF DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathbb|: \(\mathbb{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Latin Modern's \verb|\mathbb|: \(\newmathbb{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathcal|: \(\mathcal{\AtoZ}\)
    
    Latin  Modern's \verb|\mathcal|: \(\newmathcal{\AtoZ}\)
\end{document}
% END OF DOCUMENT
```

(I also received the warning `Package fontspec Warning: Font "cmsy10" does not contain requested Script "Math".`)

### What went wrong and how do I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: computer modern doesn't have blackboard bold, you mean the ams fonts, but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577603/1090

Comment: You redefinitions such as `\let\oldmathbb\mathbb` do not do what your comments say they do after such a defintion, at best, `\oldmathbb` will access whatever font has the same `\fam` as the original `\mathbb`, but it will not be the same font if you redeclared math fonts. Also you are mixing opentype math where `\mathbb` does not change fonts (`\mathbb{Z}` is character U+2124 ℤ in the same font as Z) with classic 8 bit tex fonts (where `\mathbb{Z}` s the character Z but in a different font).  Hence warnings about cmsy10.

Comment: What do you get if you explicitly call for `\old...` and `\new,,,`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I want to define `\oldmathcal` to be Computer Modern's calligraphic font in math mode and `\newmathcal` for Latin Modern's calligraphic font in math mode. Then I want to redefine `\mathcal` to be `\oldmathcal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not so clear but this shows Latin Modern Math OpenType Blackboard bold and Calligraphic alongside type 1 AMS Blackboard bold and Computer Modern Calligraphic.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{LatinModern Math}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\amsmathbb{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\cmmathcal{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$ABC \symbb{ABC} \amsmathbb{ABC}$

$ABC \symcal{ABC} \cmmathcal{ABC}$


$\bar{\cmmathcal{A}} +
 \dot{\cmmathcal{A}}$

$\bar{{\mkern-1.5mu}\cmmathcal{A}{\mkern1.5mu}} + 
 \dot{{\mkern-1.5mu}\cmmathcal{A}{\mkern1.5mu}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but if I use `\DeclareMathAlphabet\cmmathcal{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}`, how would I fix the spacing problems that occur with `\bar{\cmmathcal{A}}` or `\bar{\cmmathcal{A}}` or `\dot{\cmmathcal{A}}`? (As also seen from [a comment on this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307755/), and from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637200/).

Comment: @AmanuensisFrances that is not really the same question. If you mix fonts you may expect to need to manually adjust spacing, I added a possible tweak this time,

Comment: I apologize for not being fully clear in my original question and thank you. I also assume I can simply use a similar manual kerning for `\bar{\amsmathbb{A}}`, etc.

Comment: @AmanuensisFrances yes I just did that by eye. Depending on need and how many different values you need you could imagine implementing some command looking up some table of values you determine, or something simple like `\newcommand\shift[3]{#1{{\mkern-#2mu}#3{\mkern#2mu}}}`  so `\shift\bar{1.5}{\cmmathcal{A}}`